# How to remove the white outer glow given by UIBlurEffect

Tags: ios, swift, uivisualeffectview, uiblureffect

I wanted to present a `UIViewController` with blur background.
I used the following code in `ViewDidLoad()`

```
self.view.backgroundColor = UIColor.clear        
let blurEffect = UIBlurEffect(style: UIBlurEffectStyle.dark)
let vibrancyEffect = UIVibrancyEffect(blurEffect: blurEffect)
let blurEffectView = UIVisualEffectView(effect: vibrancyEffect)
blurEffectView.frame = self.view.bounds
blurEffectView.autoresizingMask = [.flexibleWidth, .flexibleHeight]
blurEffectView.alpha = 0.0
self.view.addSubview(blurEffectView)
self.view.sendSubview(toBack: blurEffectView)
```

The background blur is working as expected whereas the `UIViewController` that has been presented has a white glow as its border. Would be really helpful if someone can guide me how to remove that. Attaching the screenshot for reference.

[image]

Comment: You said the white glow around the presented view controller but do you mean the glow around the presenting view controller (the view controller in the background)?

Comment: @sconewolf yes. Check all the edges of the screen. You will see the glow.

Answer (score 0):

First, try removing the vibrancy effect and see if that does anything. I've had unexpected results with it in the past. But, really, the problem is that an underlying view is bleeding through the edges. Therefore, simply expand the size of the blur view so that the edges are not equal to the edges of the screen. Set the center point of the blur view equal to the center point of the presenting view controller and make the frame of the blur view 1.25x the size of the view controller's frame.

Let me know if that doesn't work for you and I'll show you how I achieved the same effect.